# How to call a javascript function with parameter

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call javascript function on "OnClick" event of a link as

```
var xx = 'test str';

breadcrumbStr = onClick="CategoryMaster.expandNode(xx)">'+xx
```

It works only when I call the function without parameter. I want to execute this function with parameter.

Please help me.Thanks

Comment: I'm terribly confused by that code. Why don't you set onClick to be "CategoryMaster.expandNode(this)" or something like that?

Comment: What is `breadcrumbStr` ? What is `onClick` here? There are syntax errors in your code. It is not all clear what you want to do...

Comment: ?? huh ? the code you posted is obviously not copy/pasted correctly. Please add a real example..

Comment: use jsfiddle.net to give a broad picture as to what your requirement is.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `breadcrumbStr` is the link you want to attach the event handler to, this is the closest what I can come up with given your code:

```
breadcrumbStr.onclick = function() {
    CategoryMaster.expandNode(xx);
}
```

Not sure what the string concatenation is about.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the senseless code...
You can use window.xx in that case. Variables are normally declared in the global scope which is window. You can access every global variable through that, which is window.xx here.

Answer (score 0):

onClick in html expects an actual function 'object'.  what you have is a funciton call.  try

```
onClick="function(){ CategoryMaster.expandNode(xx); }"
```

Comment: You are still assigning a string.